# How to format write protected sd card in ubuntu

Tags: sd-card, disk-management, usb-drive, testdisk, disk-formatting

I have a sd card with 16GB I try to format it using windows 10 it says this device is write protected when I try with Ubuntu like that `mkdosfs -F 32 -v /dev/sdh1` it says following lines.

`mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
mkdosfs: /dev/sdh1 contains a mounted filesystem.`

###### How I format this sd card?

Comment: The message is quite clear. You have to unmount the filesystem first. Open "Disks", choose your SD card and push the Stop button. Also, in "Disks" you can format the card from a GUI if you prefer that....